# aspectj-maven-plugin multi module project

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I'm trying to use [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) in a multi-module project and can't understand where [aspects](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html) have to be placed. I want to crosscut *in-module* and *between-modules* calls. Where `.aj` files should be located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did so far (structure of maven modules):

```
foo
  foo-api
  foo-impl
  foo-aspects
```

`.aj` files are located in `src/main/aspect`. All sub-modules (except `foo-aspects`) are using [`aspectLibraries`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#aspectLibraries) option of [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html), where they use aspects from `foo-aspects.jar`.

At the same time every sub-module has its own aspects in `src/main/aspect`. Works fine for me so far.